# Metric/bilinear form triangle inequality proof

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, metric-spaces, bilinear-form

Let V be a vector space and $g(u,v)$ be any symmetric, positive definite, non degenerate bilinear form defining a Euclidean scalar product in V. Define the distance function;
$$d(u,v)=g(u-v,u-v)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$
Prove that $d(u,v)$ satisfies the triangle inequality.

As intermediate steps it asks to prove the following (considering $d^2(u,v)=g(u-v,u-v)$);

a) $d(u,0)\leq d(u,v)+d(v,0)$

b) $d(u,v)=d(u+w,u+w)$

I have proved both of the above but I don't see how a) comes into use when proving the triangle inequality.

I have tried the following proof, but there must be something wrong with it since it is so simple and doesn't use a):

$d(u,w)=d(u+v,w+v)$

$~~~~~~~~~~~~=d(u,v)+d(v,w)+d(v,v)+d(u,w)$

$d(v,v)+d(u,w)\geq 0 \implies d(u,w)\leq d(u,v)+d(v,w)$

Can someone point out where my false step is, and how I am to incorporate a) into my proof? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second equality (expanding out $d$) is actually for $d^2$, which is bilinear; $d$ itself isn't.

---

What it probably wants is
$$ d(u,v) = d(u-v,0) \leq d(u-v,w-v) + d(w-v,0) = d(u,w)+d(w,v), $$
using property (a), then (b), then (a) again.

Comment: Great, thanks very much. Am I understanding you correctly when I say that your answer implies that metrics ($d$) aren't linear in their arguments ?

Comment: Yes: think about the most basic case, $\mathbb{R}$ with bilinear form $g(x,y)=xy$. Then $d(x,y)=\sqrt{g(x-y,x-y)} = \sqrt{(x-y)^2} = \lvert x-y \rvert$, clearly not bilinear.